# Sending values using unwind segue

Tags: ios, swift

hello guys i'm trying to send values using unwind segue using a button 
whenever i do this

```
 @IBAction func SENDBTN(_ sender: Any) {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindToAdd", sender: self)

        func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
            if let vc = segue.destination as? AddViewController {
                vc.longlat = self.longlat

            }
        }
    }
```

the value of longlat variable don't change in the addViewController
still nil

i'll be thankful if someone help

Comment: Is that your exact code?  If so, you need to move the `prepareForSegue` function outside of the `SENDBTN` function.

Comment: i tried that, nothing happened still nil values.

Comment: Your function signature is incorrect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have wrong code, so let try with below code and check the value of longlat variable in the addViewController.

```
@IBAction func SENDBTN(_ sender: Any) {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindToAdd", sender: self)        
    }

func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
            if let vc = segue.destination as? AddViewController {
                //vc.longlat = self.longlat
                print("entered !!!")
                vc.longlat = "hard code some value"
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for this, but i received nil whenever i print it on the viewdidload or viewdidappear

Comment: @Kamel add print("entered !!") to make sure that code run into that scope then check console, if there is no message "entered !!", plz check your id "unwindToAdd" on storyboard. Is that correct?
I guess you get a mistake with your segue :)

Comment: it worked! i had a problem with the id! thankyou all for helping me. :D

Answer (score 1):

Did you search with patience in Google?

```
@IBAction func sendData(_ sender: Any) {
         self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showData", sender: self)        
    }

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){
        if (segue.identifier == "showData"){
                let vc = segue.destination as! ProfilePage
            }
        }
```